# Save socket.io ID for all open tabs in browser

Tags: node.js, session, browser, socket.io

Can you please tell how to solve the problem of preserving the identity `socket.io`, for all open tabs in the browser.

**Example:**

I have a page open (`/index`, for example), I set it to connect to `socket.io` and get a unique session ID. But when I open the same page on another tab - ID creates another, that is, there are already two compounds with two different ID. That is right, it is logical. But, I need to send messages to these ID, simultaneously in all the tabs (including binding to `user_id`), and because the session ID are different - it is impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to (or can't) use some kind of session store, and want to send messages to multiple sockets with the same user_id, you can store a map with user_id as key and an array of socket as value

```
var socketMap = {};
```

And store a reference to the socket with your handshake data

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var userId = socket.handshake.userId;    
    if(!socketMap[userId]) socketMap[userId] = [];
    socketMap[userId].push(socket);
});
```

Or with some normal event data

```
socket.on('auth', function(data) {
    var userId = data.userId;
    var authToken = data.authToken;
    ... // verify the data...
    if(!socketMap[userId]) socketMap[userId] = [];
    socketMap[userId].push(socket);
});
```

When you want a list of socket to send message to

```
var sockets = socketMap['some_user_id'];
```

Comment: When the client disconnects, how to remove that socket from the Array?

Comment: `socket.on('disconnect', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

ID of the socket will be different in any cases, and should be not used to identify user in any case. It is only used to identify Socket it self.

What you are looking for is session. Ability to relate socket connection to session - is what you are looking for.
In order to do so, you need to have sessions created for new http connections as well as restore this session during handshake process of socket.io.
That way you will be able to identify that specific socket belongs to specific session.

And then user data and other stuff you keep to session. This helps in many cases - restore session on page refresh or have single session in multiple tabs as you need it.

Read this answer of how to restore socket.io session id from handshake process: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: The fact that I did not node.js serves full HTTP-server.
The main application I have is based on `Apache + PHP`. With `dNode`, forming a transport between `PHP` and `node.js`, which carries the user_id and the rest of meta data. In this, as such sessions I have on the node can not be.

Comment: You still have cookie sent to front-end with HTTP requests, as they are carried out to the same domain. This cookie contains data that is used to restore sessions.
You need some external storage for sessions, consider Redis or any similar storages for session data. That way PHP and node.js will be able to access your session data.

Comment: You see, there is not even in the sessions of the case. Main objective: to set your socket.id. It can be either session (which I'll get out of coockies: PHPSESID), and user_id, it does not matter.It is necessary then to send messages to Identify the session (the whole), and not just on socket.id: `IM.parentSocket.socket ('some id').emit('removeMessages', message);`

Comment: Then your question is totally irelevant to your situation. Forget about socket.id - you need to identify who socket belongs to (person), and PHPSESID is the data to help in this.
You cannot use same socket for two different connections (tabs).
So forget about socket.id as sort of solution - it is only ID of socket it self, and has nothing to do with identification of user.

Comment: See, I am sending this message to `socket.id`. I sure need it!
Sending a message from me is this: `io.socket('This socket.id, that I should be the same for all tabs.').emit('event', some_data);`